# How to hide "maxlength" in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

below is the code I use on a signup and login form restricting users to enter a limited number of characters:

```
$( "#limit1" ).attr('maxlength','11').on('input', function() {
if ($(this).val().length>=11) {
    alert('Maximum 11 characters are allowed!');       
}
});
```

However via "inspect element" they're able to edit maximum length in html and submit forms.

So how can I stop this? I'm looking for any suitable solution to prevent users from registering/entering characters more than allowed.

Comment: You check the length also at server-side, and boomerang the form, if there are too many characters. You can't prevent users to use dev tools.

Comment: You fix it on the server. You can ajax the value to alert normal users and reject the value from the server if people insist. However why the limit? Are you running a mainframe from the 80s?

Comment: You should **never** trust the client. Always validate on server side, then either truncate the value, or throw an error depending on your use case.

Comment: You will need to do both: client-side checking to make the form quick and server-side to have the safety that nobody can fool you.

Comment: Even the best JavaScript solution cannot stop a request going to your server with bogus data.

Comment: They do not event need to use your form or even your webpage to submit the data.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay, took a note of that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb in web development, **never trust any client input**, because **there is no way to stop anyone to open the developer tools** in a web browser and edit what they want. Also most of registration page garbage data comes from bots and they will directly post to your registration page without even bothering with any check you might write.

So while you can put some additional checks client-side to avoid real-time server checks and keep your website running fast, **you must always check the data server-side**, and inform the client accordingly if he tries to input incorrect data in the form.

There are some answers that require JavaScript to work. A lot of bots simply ignore JavaScript and will post some data to your server as they want and will not be bothered by any client-side code.

So just verify the data on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put return false to prevent submit form.

```
  $( "#limit1" ).attr('maxlength','11').on('input', function() {
        if ($(this).val().length>=11) {
            alert('Maximum 11 characters are allowed!');       
            return false;
        }
        });
```

Comment: Bots won't be bothered.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/9pc782eb/2/

```js
$('#limit1').keypress(function(e){
   if($(this).val().length >= 11) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Maximum 11 characters are allowed!'); 
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="limit1" />
```

On **keypress** restrict the user.

Comment: Like JG73 answer, bots won't be bothered to post any data they want.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Shiladitya!! You're a life saver!! :)

Comment: @ZohrabinClean .. Ya you can use it.